# In C4 model, "External" means External to the Org or External to the System scope?

Tags: architecture, diagrams

I am currently drawing a "C4 Containers" Architecture diagram using C4 Model.  The Core Software System of System Context diagram is now exploded further into the Containers diagram (should I say it is a Zoomed-in view?).

I have a few software systems that are *external* to this Core Software System but still part of my Organization (for example, systems that are running on-premises within the Org, such as an Data Analytics system, Org HR System, etc).  The development team for such systems are going to be different teams (but (obviously) some team from within the Org itself).  I also have to depict few systems that are really *external* to the Organisation itself (for example, a Saas Vendor system for sending emails, etc).

Now the question is, should I depict both external systems as "External" (in C4 diagram style, a "gray" box)?  In other words, **in C4 model, the term "External" means External to the Org or External to the System scope?**

(If that matters -  Technical details to the former external systems are half-known (like they use REST API and on-premises, but not sure whether they are on cloud or on premises), whereas for the latter external systems (3rd party vendor systems), almost not much technical details.)

Comment: You're the modeler - it means what you (and your team) define it to mean. If  you need to distinguish the two kinds of external systems, just annotate them somehow (or color code them, or whatever). Doesn't hurt to also include a legend. As long as the people looking at the diagram agree on what these things mean, there is no problem.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thanks for that, customizing should just work, however, I wanted to understand what C4 originally had for this situation.  I don't want to deviate away from what C4 model suggested (as they had only 2 notations - one for Internal (blue) and another one for External (gray)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of C4 modeling, external systems are any systems beyond the boundaries of the system being modeled. If your "Core Software System" is what is being modeled, you would define the boundaries of that "Core Software System" and anything else, regardless of if it is within your organization or not, is considered an external system. Keep in mind that, even in a Container diagram, the external system is depicted by a single element connected to the containers that interface with the system - you do not decompose the external systems into containers or components.

Comment: In that case, both the internal-to-Org-but-BB and external-to-Org systems are depicted in similar fashion (i.e. as external systems (gray) only).  It there are 5 & 5 such systems present in the diagram, it makes it difficult for execution teams to differentiate between them (for example, to get effort estimations, etc).  Looks like customization as Filip suggested above is the way to go.  Thanks for your answer, solves my case, will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar Have you considered that you may need textual descriptions beyond what the C4 model calls for? Annotation, such as [<<Vendor Name's>> System] could work along with the explanatory text within the element on the model, but C4 models aren't designed to stand fully on their own. Having additional text or tables with key contacts and vendors can help give additional information beyond the graphical diagrams.

Comment: Yes, I have added textual descriptions to all internal/external systems with the Annotations like you suggested.  At the moment, as the External systems are less compared to internal-to-org-but-external-to-core systems, I am denoting those "true" External systems with a special icon to differentiate.  That works for now.  Thanks.